# ret is causing a segfault in assembly

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I have the following Assembly code:

```
.text
.global main
main:
    push %r13
    push %r14
    push %r15
    jmp rest
x:    
    .data
    y0:    .quad   0
    .text
    mov %r14, y0
    mov $format,%rdi
    push y0
    popq %rsi
    movq %rsi, %r15
    call printf
    mov $format,%rdi
    mov $10,%rsi
    call printf
    ret
rest:    
    movq $5, %r9
    pushq %r9
    popq %rsi
    movq %rsi, %r14
    jmp x
    mov $0,%rax
    pop %r15
    pop %r14
    pop %r13
    ret
.data
format:
.byte 37
.byte 108
.byte 117
.byte 0
```

I was hoping that the ret would make the program jump back to where it was: however, I get a segmentation fault. Why is this?

Comment: Stuff like `pushq %r9` `popq %rsi` seems like it would be simpler by replacing with `mov %r9, %rsi`

Comment: I recommend stepping through your code in a debugger like _GDB_

Comment: Please stop changing the very nature of your first question. If you have a different question please create a new question. Your changes make the comments and the answers nonsensical. I have reversed your change to the original version once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These issues are almost *always* caused by failing to clean up the stack.  The same is true in your case.

You begin with:

```
main:
    push %r13
    push %r14
    push %r15
    jmp rest
```

Within `rest` you then

```
jmp x
```

Within `x` you do this:

```
mov $format,%rdi
mov $10,%rsi
call printf
ret
```

This leaves you with three things sitting on the stack that you have not dealt with.  When this `ret` is executed, it moves the previous value of `%r15` into the instruction pointer and segfaults.

`ret` will not return from a jump.  It returns to the instruction following a `call`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I updated my code based on your response (pushing a $0 so that that is popped instead of %r15), but I'm confused as to why it's still not working.

Comment: Because you are pushing more things onto the stack than you are pulling back off.  Your POPs should always be equal to your PUSHs, or you must adjust SP/ESP/RSP to unwind the stack manually.  The return pointer for your call is stored on the stack.  If the stack pointer isn't pointing to it when you hit a RET, it will load whatever the top value on the stack is into the EIP/RIP, which will almost always cause a segfault.